# dragging behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, html, css

i created a red div.Using mouse cursor i can move it anywhere on the screen.it was fine and smooth.then i decided to add an extra orange div inside the red div.i made the positioning "absolute" for the red div and "relative" for the orange div.as soon as i put the orange div inside the red div the position changing is not smooth .if i click on the orange portion an then move it is smooth but if i clip the visible red portion and move my mouse it is not smooth.how to fix this..

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXH7j/1/)

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #mydiv {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            top: 300px;
            left: 200px;
        }
        #mid {
            position: relative;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            margin: 30px 30px;
            background-color: orange;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mydiv">
        <div id="mid"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var gotit = false;
        var i, p, q;
        var divs = document.getElementById("mydiv");
        divs.addEventListener('mousedown', clipit, false);
        divs.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            moveit(e);
        }, false);
        divs.addEventListener('mouseup', unclip, false);
        divs.addEventListener('mouseout', unclip, false);

        function clipit() {
            i = divs.offsetLeft;
            gotit = true;

            p = e.clientX;
            q = e.clientY;
        }

        function moveit(e) {

            if (gotit == true) {

                if (e.clientX > divs.offsetLeft) {

                    divs.style.left = divs.offsetLeft + (e.clientX - p) + "px";
                    p = e.clientX;
                }
                if (e.clientY > divs.offsetTop) {
                    divs.style.top = divs.offsetTop + (e.clientY - q) + "px";
                    q = e.clientY;
                }
            }
        }

        function unclip() {
            gotit = false;

        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put the event in clipit:

```
function clipit(e) {}
```

Remember to always check your console log:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

[fix](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/tXH7j/2/)

Comment: thanks a lot :) !! it was moving though.so i didn't think of any error!!

Comment: No problem, good luck. [= Remember to choose this as the correct answer. Thanks.